# Converting list with 1 variable to float in Python

Tags: python, list, type-conversion

I have a list variable with one element,

```
x=['2']
```

and I want to convert it to a float:

```
x=2.0
```

I tried `float(x)`, or `int(x)` - without success.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the first item in your one-item list to a `float`. The approaches you tried already are trying to convert the whole list to a `float` (or an `int` - not sure where you were going with that!).

Python is zero-indexed (index numbers start from zero) which means that the first item in your list is referred to as `x[0]`.

So the snippet you need is:

```
x = float(x[0])
```